# Package convert from .doc to html

Tags: node.js, mammoth

I am using mammoth `npm` package to convert `docx` to `html`, but it is not usable for `doc` files.
So which package to use to convert `doc` files? I have searched many but not found.

I am using `nodejs`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you could find a package allowing you to convert doc files (and if you ever find one, I doubt it will have a good accuracy).

DOCX is an open file format (it's just XML : DOC**X**), whereas the DOC format is proprietary, so it will be way harder to get the wanted informations, if even possible.